# Is this a BIG bug of Microsoft's implementation of std::thread?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, c++11, stdthread

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void Hello()
{}

int main()
{
    {
        std::thread(Hello).join();
    }    

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

The output windows shows: (VC++ compiler version: Nov 2012 CTP)

```
The thread 0x5ab8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{261} normal block at 0x002A2E00, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The thread 0x5abc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5ab4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[0x5A94] C++11.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Make this in a for loop and take a look if leak is growing or not. It may be some lazy initialized data structures that are initialized only once and seem to be "leak".

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757212/vs-2012-rc-std-thread-reports-memory-leak-even-on-stack ?

Comment: @Aschratt You should turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: Leak detection is imperfect, especially for implementation-specific runtime-owned objects that _it knows_ it'll get around to cleaning up later.

Comment: `Note: Connect doesn't notify me about comments. If you have any further questions, please E-mail me.` Bah. I find it hard to explain why, but this just sums up Microsoft for me.

Comment: Yeah, don't we all dislike Microsoft developers that leave their email address for everybody to use.  Stephan always responds, if the message isn't the typical MS hate anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the following MS Connect entry:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757212/vs-2012-rc-std-thread-reports-memory-leak-even-on-stack